# find the number of elements in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to file the row length of a column from the dataframe.

dataframe name- df

```
sample data:
a   b   c
1   d   ['as','the','is','are','we']
2   v   ['a','an']
3   t   ['we','will','pull','this','together','.']

expected result:
a   b   c                                          len
1   d   ['as','the','is','are','we']               5
2   v   ['a','an']                                 2
3   t   ['we','will','pull','this','together','.'] 6
```

Till now, i have just tried:

```
df.loc[:,'len']=len(df.c)
```

but this gives me the total rows present in the dataframe. 
How can i get the elements in each row of a specific column of a dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

One way, is to use `apply` and calculate len

```
In [100]: dff
Out[100]:
   a  b                                    c
0  1  d               [as, the, is, are, we]
1  2  v                              [a, an]
2  3  t  [we, will, pull, this, together, .]

In [101]: dff['len'] = dff['c'].apply(len)

In [102]: dff
Out[102]:
   a  b                                    c  len
0  1  d               [as, the, is, are, we]    5
1  2  v                              [a, an]    2
2  3  t  [we, will, pull, this, together, .]    6
```